# Setting up Gulp browserSync correctly

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

[image: Folder Directory]

I have trouble setting up Gulp correctly with the current folder structure as shown above.

Here's my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('../public/scss/*')
    .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'public'
    },
  })
})

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function (){
  gulp.watch('../public/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
  gulp.watch('views/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('../public/javascript/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('../public/css/**/*.css', browserSync.reload);
});
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/styles.css">
  <title>FCC Image Search Abstraction</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I do have a scss folder in the public folder.

EDIT: My index.html is located inside the views folder

What am I doing wrong? In my console.log, it says that it cant GET its styles.css

Comment: Pretty hard to tell what's wrong without looking at your entire directory structure. At a glance I'd guess you have a problem with relative paths. It's pretty unusual to have your build files and static files in the same directory. Try adding `.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))` instead of just the simple sass() method and see what she says.

Comment: I'd also try to change your scss source to something like `return gulp.src('../public/scss/**/*.scss')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BrowserSync is serving public on /

```
server: { baseDir: 'public'},
```

Try to change the css link in your html for

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```